# ng-container unexpected behavior with *ngIf directive

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have an ng-container in my project that should show/hide a part of my HTML depending on a certain property.

When the property is initially false and afterwards I set it to true - the content inside the ng-container shows up as expected. However when the property is initially true - the content just doesn't show up.

The HTML code:

```
<ion-item>
  <ng-container *ngIf="prop">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked  [innerHTML]="htmlString"></ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox (click)="checkboxClick($event)"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  </ng-container>
  </ion-item>
```

**Here is an [EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-fbrome?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html) of the initial property being false. 
When it is changed to true, the content shows.**

**Here is an [EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-uddru5?file=pages/home/home.ts) of the initial property being true. 
And nothing shows up.**

What can be done to show the content if the value is initially true?

Comment: please don't just spam tags;  instead of tagging every single version of ionic, it would be better if you just tag the version you are actually using.

Comment: It appears that having nested `ion-item` elements causes the problem in [your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-uddru5). See [this modified stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-kpmzcr).

Comment: @ConnorsFan that does work, but I feel like having initialization logic in the class definition as he did is pretty **wrong** too, a code smell perhaps.

Comment: @gfels Just don't nest the `ion-item' and it completely fixes the issue. Another thing is you should not be accessing a private member variable from the template, and if you want there to be an initial value set, you can set it when you declare it. [modified stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-datsgx?file=pages/home/home.ts)

Comment: @AustinTFrench Sorry, changed the initialization to ionViewWillLoad(). That's how it's implemented in my project and the content doesn't show up.

Comment: @Jacques The structure is a bit bigger in my project - the outer ion-item is needed. It all worked perfectly without the ng-container. Sure, it's better to make the member public, but that doesn't affect the outcome for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the issue is that you need to define that the ng-container contains content for the ion-item.

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-datsgx?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

[Documented on the ionic framework site.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/Item/#content-and-inputs)

```html
<ion-item>
  <ng-container *ngIf="prop" item-content> <!-- this right here -->
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked  [innerHTML]="htmlString"></ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox (click)="checkboxClick($event)"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
  </ng-container>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Thanks, this saved me. Didn't understand why though. The documentation link you provided doesn't really explain it at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies on how `ion-item` renders its template. Because you have an `ion-label` inside your container, the parent `ion-item` assumes your item content is inside this `ion-label` found on the template; therefore ignoring all the rest.

So the problem is not really the `ng-container` but `ion-item` it self, and when it starts with `prop=false`, it's not rendered until angular detect changes and build this specific portion of the code; hence `ion-item` gets built correctly. But when it starts `true` `ion-item` itself throw it away.

The whole `ion-item` template:

```
template:
    '<ng-content select="[item-start],[item-left],ion-checkbox:not([item-end]):not([item-right])"></ng-content>' +
    '<div class="item-inner">' +
      '<div class="input-wrapper">' +
        '<ng-content select="ion-label"></ng-content>' +
        '<ion-label *ngIf="_viewLabel">' +
          '<ng-content></ng-content>' +
        '</ion-label>' +
        '<ng-content select="ion-select,ion-input,ion-textarea,ion-datetime,ion-range,[item-content]"></ng-content>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<ng-content select="[item-end],[item-right],ion-radio,ion-toggle"></ng-content>' +
      '<ion-reorder *ngIf="_hasReorder"></ion-reorder>' +
    '</div>' +
'<div class="button-effect"></div>'
```

[ion-item.ts line 274](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/c463b065c79481939de958ec6eb9c7827c62ec2f/src/components/item/item.ts#L274)

As it can be seen below, it look up for an `ion-label` (first line `select="ion-label"`) and if it's found, it uses it as the content of the item, otherwise it creates a new `ion-label` with the content of your `ion-item` within it (`ng-content`).

The relevant part of `ion-item` template:

```
'<ng-content select="ion-label"></ng-content>' +
'<ion-label *ngIf="_viewLabel">' +
    '<ng-content></ng-content>' +
'</ion-label>' +
'<ng-content select="ion-select,ion-input,ion-textarea,ion-datetime,ion-range,[item-content]"></ng-content>' +
```

In the end, it's just a conflict between component because you are using one `ion-item` inside another.

On way to solve this is using `<ng-container *ngIf="prop" item-content>` (as suggested by @Jacques's), it will make the slot be captured by the third slot described before which selects the `[item-content]` as a target not losing the content in spite of having an `ion-label` on your child `ion-item`.

```
'<ng-content select="ion-select,ion-input,ion-textarea,ion-datetime,ion-range,[item-content]"></ng-content>' +
```

> **Disclaimer:** I only give my answer because the previous answer doesn't explain why this happen, consider this a complement.